# Trying to use spaces in an array of search variables, but not getting the expected output / results

Tags: php

I cannot seem to get this working. I am trying to modify a very old script (of our late technician and close friend) which we use to be used for searching servers with which OS being used. This consists (as far as I can tell) out PHP and SMARTY.

I already tried escaping the content with slashes and using backticks. But it simply does not work. I really have no idea where to look. Below are the original two pieces of code (I couldn't find more parts for it, or I have overlooked).

Piece of PHP code from the 1st PHP-file:

```
$values['osname'] = array( '-' => 'no choice',
                          '5' => 'CentOS 5.x',
                          '6' => 'CentOS 6.x',
                          '7' => 'CentOS 7.x',
                        );
```

Piece of code from the 2nd PHP-file:

```
$osname = intval(Common::GPvar('osname'));
$_SESSION['form']['serverselect']['osname'] = $osname;
if ($osname != '-') { $where .= " AND dsh.sumup LIKE '%OS: CentOS ".$osname."%'"; }
```

This is being used in a search form, so when I select "CentOS 6.x" it will display all servers which have the text **OS: CentOS 6.10** in it.

Now what I am trying to achieve is to make the following to work:

```
$values['osname'] = array( '-' => 'no choice',
                          'CentOS 5' => 'CentOS 5.x',
                          'CentOS 6' => 'CentOS 6.x',
                          'CentOS 7' => 'CentOS 7.x',
                          'Virtuozzo 7' => 'Virtuozzo 7.x',
                        );
```

I tried to escape the content, as I mentioned above, however that didn't work. So I am guessing the coding in the 2nd PHP-file also needs some adjusting. So I tried removing certain stuff, like "CentOS", "%" and several other things. But it does not work. The result is that, on a search, I am getting all servers being displayed (no matter what OS is on them).

I guess I did correctly on escaping the variables in the array, but the 2nd piece of coding is not compatible for some reason with the requested search input?

Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove intval(...) because intval will turn strings into integers

https://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

```
$osname = Common::GPvar('osname');
```

The whole code

```
$osname = Common::GPvar('osname');
$_SESSION['form']['serverselect']['osname'] = $osname;
if ($osname != '-') { $where .= " AND dsh.sumup LIKE '".$osname."%'"; }
```

Comment: Nevermind. I am an idiot, made a typo! Sorry. It's working now and I will follow-up on some reading with the link you provided! TY!